# Relative View Align 2 text view, one left align and one right align

Tags: android, android-view

Using a relative view, how can I alight 2 text-views in the same line? one has to be stuck to the left and the other onto the right.

If you are a web developer, you can imagin it as applying `float:left` and `float:right` to the 2 text-views respectively

**Textview 1:** Will contain an event title
**Textview 2:** Will contain the event's time
**I want the TextView 2 to be shorter since it will only contain a time whereas TextView1 will contain an event's title**

*I hope a relative layout is a good approach for this*

I want something like this: 

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_lay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Or

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I had previously tried your first solution, the text from TextView1 overlaps TextView2. Your Solution 2 seems to work!

Comment: the first solution obviously does not work, as text and text1 have no relation rule. a `toLeftOf` at least would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the width of each to be equal you can use a LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" />
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I see but I don't want the width to be equal. The second text view will just contain a time `(3:00 pm)` and the first textView will contain an event's title `(A talk show on blablabla)` so the first textview has to be longer

Comment: So just do a Linear with wrap_content for the layout_width of the TextViews.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Linear aligned at the top with some weights for each TextView or use a Relative like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_lay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="left"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

However, I prefer a linear inside a Relative with both texts.